# Check if user is in AD group using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, ad

I need to check if user is part of an AD Group with Javascript.

I've created a SP group and I added an AD Group to it and I am part of this group.

I removed my user from Site Administrators and Site owners (group with full control).

Then I tried the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673723/2185964

But the code above did not worked. Is it possible that it is an issue caused by users profile sync? Or there is a way to add to SharePoint user profile the AD group or OU or AD directory where an user belongs and get this property using JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using SharePointPlus for this kind of operations. You can check this.
https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/people.html#distributionLists

Comment: I didn't know SharePointPlus, but it seems great! But getUserInfo returns always "User cannot be found" (also checking with "domain\\myuser")

Comment: Yes, It's a great library. Thanks to @AymKdn who is a member of this platform :)